# How to sum the values per key of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array like the following:

```
$items = array(
    'red' => array(
        '1' => array(2),
        '2' => array(6, 1)
    ),
    'green' => array(
        '2' => array(1, 9),
        '1' => array(1, 2)
    )
);
```

I'm trying to find sum of values in the array. I want output like this:

```
array (
    [1] => 5,
    [2] => 17

)
```

I tried like this:

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($items as $k => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
        $sumArray[$id] += $value;
    }
}
print_r($sumArray);
```

But I got errors like this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /path/to/file.php on line NN
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /path/to/file.php:NN

Comment: Please put some code highlighting in your question. One can not read it at all.

Comment: So what have you tried? I see no code...

Comment: I tried like this $sumArray = array();

foreach ($items as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($sumArray);

Comment: i got a fatalerror like this :Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Comment: @limimathew Could you add your code from your comment to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` and use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).
You could add the sum of the array by storing the key in `$sumArray`.

First check if the key already exists using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). If it does not exists, you add the sum for the first time. If it does exists, you add it the the existing value.

```
$sumArray = [];
foreach ($items as $date) {
    foreach ($date as $key => $amounts) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $sumArray)) {
            $sumArray[$key] = array_sum($amounts);
            continue;
        }
        $sumArray[$key] += array_sum($amounts);
    }
}
print_r($sumArray);
```

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 17

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RKANK)